# ASP.Net AJAX issue in IE6 - Windows 2000 machine

Tags: asp.net-ajax, internet-explorer-6

Are there any known issues with ASP.Net Ajax and IE6 in Windows 2000 machines ?

We have implemented ASP.Net AJAX in our web application. We have used UpdatePanel to implement ajax (Page content is refreshed based on User action.)

We are seeing an issue in windows 2000 machines with IE 6.  The Ajax calls are failing with the error  'Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerTimeoutException: The server request timed out.'

We do not think this is really a timeout issue because
1) We have set timeout to a large value >30 minutes. 
2) The javascript error is thrown immediately after user action

We have used the Toolkitscriptmanager control (part of ajaxcontrol toolkit)

Has anyone come across similar issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We changed the timeout to a lesser value like 3000 and the issue went away.